# Cognito authentication and Single Sign On

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, amazon-cognito

I have a web page were the user signs in using Amazon Cognito and AWS Amplify authentication. I have a link into that application that opens another aplication. I want a Single Sign On (I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this), however, I have read a little about it, that there is information about getting the ID Token and the Access Token to login to the other application. How can I use that JWT token to access to my application? 
[The expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXETH.png)

Answer (score 3):

After authentication, your application can query tokens from Cognito User Pool (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html)

Your app can, in turn, pass a token to the second app (the target of the SSO) as a HTTP header.

The second app will verify the token (i.e. verify the signature and the claim, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-verifying-a-jwt.html) and grant access to authorised users.

In case no token is provided, or an invalid token, the second app will redirect to an authentication page.

Comment: If the second app already exists and has its own authentication, I should create an alternative authentication which accepts the cognito token?

Comment: @Sébastien Stormacq Does the second app need to make calls to Cognito via API or just the JWT validation is all that is needed? Also, do we need to pass all the three tokens (ID, Access and Refresh) to the second app for this to work?

Comment: Also, wouldn't hosted UI be best for this case, i.e. build the hosted URL with redirect to the second app, if user is already logged in, cognito redirects user to the second app with a token in the URL query parameter (of course with "Implicit Grant"), and then the second app simply validates that token's validity and logs the user in?

Comment: As described here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html : the sending App must get the JWT token and pass it to the receiving app (it might be a base64 query string param or an HTTP header).  The receiving app needs to verify the JWT token as described in the doc

Comment: Note that passing the token via header, instead of query string parameter, is considered more secure. '

Comment: absolutely do NOT send it via query param because that is not secure. Header would be fine.